# Empty field Data Type in springfox swagger ui

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a Spring Web MVC application with rest services and I try to use Springfox for automated docs for it.

I use

```
io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.5.0
io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.5.0
org.webjars:swagger-ui:2.1.4
```

My SwaggerConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile("dev")
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
        return docket;
    }
}
```

And:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Profile("dev")
public class SwaggerWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

I have a rest controller:

```
@Api
@RestController
@RequestMapping(RegistrationRestController.ROOT_PATH)
public class RegistrationRestController {
    private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(RegistrationRestController.class);
    public static final String ROOT_PATH = "/rest/registration";

    private final ResponseUtil responseUtil;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public RegistrationRestController(ResponseUtil responseUtil, UserService userService) {
        log.debug("Instantiate RegistrationRestController bean");
        this.responseUtil = Objects.requireNonNull(responseUtil);
        this.userService = Objects.requireNonNull(userService);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {""}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Create new user and authorize them. Returns access token", response = AccessTokenDTO.class)
    })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create new user", response = AccessTokenDTO.class)
    public ResponseDTO newUserRegistration(@Valid @ApiParam(required = true) RegistrationDTO registrationDTO) {
        log.debug("POST {} with registrationDTO='{}'", ROOT_PATH, registrationDTO.toString());

        AccessTokenDTO accessToken = userService.createUserAndAuthorize(registrationDTO);

        return responseUtil.wrapResult(accessToken);
    }
}
```

And RegistrationDTO:

```
@ApiModel
public class RegistrationDTO {
    @NotNull(message = "registrationDTO.phone.notNull.fail")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{10}", message = "registrationDTO.phone.pattern.fail")
    private String phone;
    @NotNull(message = "registrationDTO.email.notNull.fail")
    @Email(message = "registrationDTO.email.pattern.fail")
    private String email;
    @NotNull(message = "registrationDTO.lastName.notNull.fail")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "registrationDTO.lastName.size.fail")
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull(message = "registrationDTO.firstName.notNull.fail")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "registrationDTO.firstName.size.fail")
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull(message = "registrationDTO.password.notNull.fail")
    @Size(min = 6, message = "registrationDTO.password.size.fail")
    private String password;
    @NotNull(message = "registrationDTO.passwordConfirmation.notNull.fail")
    @Size(min = 6, message = "registrationDTO.passwordConfirmation.size.fail")
    private String passwordConfirmation;

    @AssertTrue(message = "registrationDTO.isPasswordMatch.fail")
    public boolean isPasswordMatch() {
        return Objects.equals(password, passwordConfirmation);
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPasswordConfirmation() {
        return passwordConfirmation;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirmation(String passwordConfirmation) {
        this.passwordConfirmation = passwordConfirmation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RegistrationDTO{" +
                "phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

But when I'm opening localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html I see an empty Data type for RegistrationDTO parameter.

[image: Empty data type]

[image: JSON Definitions]

What I'm doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify @RequestBody before method parameter